# How to loop the values stored in a list in a url?

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

```
i = ['Link_1/','Link_2/','Link_3/']

my_url ='http://www.example.com/category/{}'.format(i)
```

I'm trying to create a loop so that all the values from i can be there.But I am stuck with what I need to do further.

Comment: Your syntax is very broken. Please fix it. Also, please make an attempt to wrap your statement in a loop since you already know that that's what you need to do.

Comment: I have just started learning python
@MadPhysicist

Comment: That is not an excuse for not matching your quotes and missing commas. The syntax highlighting of your own question should help you fix the problem.

Comment: @MadPhysicist edited it.
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the update.

Comment: It's '...'.format(value) and not '...'format.(value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do with each URL, you will want to use an explicit loop (like [`for`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) or [`while`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming)), or a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

If you want to just get a list of formatted strings, the simplest way would be to use a list comprehension:

```
my_urls = ['http://www.example.com/category/{}'.format(link) for link in i]
```

Notice that I changed `.../{}'format.(url)'` to `.../{}'.format(url)'`. The dot [separates the object from it's method](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces). In this case, the object is the [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) `'http://www.example.com/category/{}'`. That string has a [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method, which you access by doing `string.format(...)`.

If you want to do more advanced processing on each element of the list `i`, not just format the links, you can use a `for` loop:

```
for link in i:
    my_url = 'http://www.example.com/category/{}'.format(link)
    # Do what you need to do to `my_url` before you move on to the next link
```

Please take some time to read through the links I posted to the official Python documentation. It may help you work through similar problems on your own in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Much Appreciated.I will surely read through the links.

Answer (score 0):

Python has list comprehension for this:

```
links = ['Link_1/','Link_2/', 'Link_3']
my_urls = ['http://www.example.com/category/{}'.format(url) for url in links]
```

Comment: Thanks for this.I am still getting a prompt of Invalid Syntax and it is highlighting format in red color.Can you help me on this?

Comment: The error on format was already in the question. Fixed in the answere now.